# Comparison between intN_t and uintN_t

Tags: c

I'm puzzled. Example:

```
int x=-1; 
unsigned y=0;
(x<y) ----> false

int8_t x=-1;
unint8_t y=0;
(x<y) ----> true
```

Additionally, the compiler raises warnings on the first comparison, but not the second. It seems that for

- (int vs unsigned) - int promoted to unsigned
- (intN_t vs uintN_t) - uintN_t promoted to intN_t

Why have this behaviour? Like... really?

Comment: int8_t and uint8_t are char

Comment: @0A0D same result for int16_t, int32_t, ..

Comment: @PeteFordham: See ecatmur's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you apply any binary arithmetic operator (including comparisons) to a pair of numeric types which are both shorter than `int`, C converts both operands to `int` before performing the operation.

Whenever you apply any binary arithmetic operator to a pair of numeric types which are the same size, mismatched in signedness, and *not* shorter than `int`, C converts the signed operand to unsigned before the operation.

These are two of the "[integer promotion](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/)" rules.  They are not terribly intuitive, and they are probably not what one would do if one were designing C from scratch today, but they are what they are and we are stuck with them.

Answer (score 4):

This is a result of the usual integer conversions.

In the first case, both operands have rank at least that of `int`, and have the same rank, so they are converted to the unsigned integer type.

In the second case, `int8_t` is `char` (it has to be, if it exists at all), so both operands are promoted to `int`.  Both `-1` and `0` are representable in `int`, so there is no warning.

Comment: `short` can't be 8 bits, it is required to be able to represent at least the interval [-32767, 32767] (yes, not -32768, due to C99's bizarre belief that non-twos-complement arithmetic was still worth bothering to support).  If `char` is *larger* than 8 bits, however, `int8_t` could be a special extended type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/697531/195488

Comment: If char is larger than 8 bits, you probably won't have int8_t (it's one of the types that's optional for an implementation to provide because the standard writers would like to think someone will implement C99 for a UNIVAC running somewhere).

Comment: @Zack oh, of course; forgot the minimum sizes.